# $.ajax request in Rails 4 app doesn't render view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to submit model data to a controller method, from javascxript, and render the list of results...

```
function submitResults() {
  resultURL = "/result";
  resultData = JSON.stringify(results);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: resultURL,
    data: { results: resultData},
    contentType: "application/html",
    dataType: "html"
  });
```

The server shows the controller method is executed and the view is rendered...

```
Started POST "/result" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-14 17:36:32 -0600
Processing by ResultsController#create as HTML
  Result Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "results".* FROM "results"
  Rendered results/index.html.erb within layouts/application (366.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4722ms (Views: 408.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

but the browser doesn't render the view. Here's my create method that's triggered by the $.ajax call...

```
def create
  result = Result.new(result_params)
  result.save
  @results = Result.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :index }
  end
end
```

Why doesn't the browser load the index view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ajax call is not doing anything with the response, define callback functions for it. E.g.:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: resultURL,
  data: { results: resultData},
  contentType: "application/html",
  dataType: "html"
}).done(function(response) {
  //attach the response somewhere in the DOM.
});
```

Check the [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) doc for all callbacks.

BTW, you usually do not want to load a whole html page through an ajax call. Seems like the page you are rendering includes everything (seems to be using the default layout). In such a case, making AJAX calls can have no benefits (and make things harder) and you might want to do the post through an html form.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just update the answer. In your case, I suggest going with an html call. javascript has no benefit here. But if you want to do it with jquery, you can use $(document).html(response), which will keep the url the same, but change the whole DOM.

Comment: Thanks again, that makes sense. I'm really just trying to figure out a way to call my create method from javascript. Using $.ajax is the only way I've found so far. What do you mean by "html call"? Can you provide a quick code snippet that I can use to research futher?

Comment: Well, if you want to do it through javascript, then $.ajax is the best way, but again I suggest that if the result of the POST (call to create) is going to be a browser page change, then do not do it through javascript. Rails has helper methods that help you create html forms (I mean html, with no javascript). See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't use forms due to some of the tools I'm using to create the data that I'm posting. If I can't use forms and you don't suggest I submit through javascript, is there simply no solution? Either way, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks. It depends, you can still do so through javascript but changing your controller to return a page partial, a javascript script or a json object. OR you can have javascript prepare an html form you already have in the dom on page load(which seems to not be possible in your case). There might be other ways I am not aware of too.

Comment: What's preventing you from using a regular html form?  Even if you have dynamic data you can add that data as hidden form elements and still submit the form as you wish.